# Why variable value is not showing in insert query

Tags: php, pdo

I have this code snippet

```
$taskAssignedCompleteId = $row["TaskAssignCompletionId"];
echo "taskAssignedCompleteId::".$taskAssignedCompleteId. "\n";

if($taskAssignedCompleteId == 0 || $taskAssignedCompleteId = null)
{
    echo "Currently no task assigned to you. If you are not doing a task on PMS and still receving this massage then, contact your team lead";
    return;
}

$sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO emp_task_finished_request (EmpTaskAssignCompletionId, RequestDateTime) VALUES (".$taskAssignedCompleteId.", '$date')";
echo "output : ".$sqlInsert;
$queryInsert = $connPDO->exec($sqlInsert);

    echo "\n output : ".$queryInsert;
```

Surprisingly `$taskAssignedCompleteId` value is not showing in query when i echo my `$queryInsert` varaiable while it is perfectly showing when i directly `echo $taskAssignedCompleteId`. Why is the problem? it is very strange for me.
here is my output

```
taskAssignedCompleteId::13
sqlInsert full : INSERT INTO emp_task_finished_request (EmpTaskAssignCompletionId, RequestDateTime) VALUES (, '2017-07-05 16:53:45')
 output :
```

Comment: Not much point using PDO and then introducing an [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) vector by not using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Can you look this `$taskAssignedCompleteId = null` I think there should be `==`

Comment: Why do you have $taskAssignedCompleteId = null? It should be "=="

Comment: you should use == for comparison

Comment: @Mr.Developer love you i seriously missed that thanks

Comment: @RiggsFolly i am waiting to accept answer, i hope you know stack-overflow waiting policy to accept answer

Comment: I do, but as you have only accepted 7 out of your last 30 questions I though I would provide you a gentle reminder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to correct your if statement. `$taskAssignedCompleteId = null` is not correct. Kindly replace it by following

```
if($taskAssignedCompleteId == 0 || $taskAssignedCompleteId == null)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use `==` for `comparison` operator . `=` is `assignment` operator .so it's assigning `null` to `$taskAssignedCompleteId` variable .

```
if($taskAssignedCompleteId == 0 || $taskAssignedCompleteId == null) { .. }
```

Comment: You should also put this at comment box.

Comment: if it's answer . i can post it in answer area . whats wrong with it @JaydeepMor

Answer (score 0):

Change `$taskAssignedCompleteId = null` to `$taskAssignedCompleteId == null`

By doing this, you are assigning `taskAssignedCompleteId` to a null value. To compare use "==" but you already know that. Just a typo I guess.

Darn, somebody beat me to the answer as I'm typing this.